# Removing single quotation marks while preserving apostrophes Python, NLTK

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I'm trying to create a frequency list of a corpus of poetry. The code reads the .txt file and creates a .csv with the data.

The part I am struggling with is in removing irrelevant punctuation from the text. The relevant code I have so far is:

```
import nltk

raw = open('file_name.txt', 'r').read()
output = open('output_filename.csv','w')
txt = raw.lower()

pattern = r'''(?x)([A_Z]\.)+|\w+(-\w+)*|\.\.\|[][.,;"'?():-_`]'''
tokenized = nltk.regexp_tokenize(txt,pattern)
```

This works almost perfectly, as it preserves the hyphens in words such as *chimney-sweeper*,  but it also cuts contractions into two separate words, which is not what I want.

For example, my text file (trial run is on William Blake's Songs of Innocence) has the lines:

> 'Pipe a song about a Lamb!'

which I would like to be

> Pipe | a | song | about | a | Lamb

The code I was using before  kept the contractions intact, but also left me with the single quotation marks attached to the word:

```
for punct in string.punctuation:
    txt = txt.replace(punct,' ')
re.sub(r'\r+',' ',txt)
```

So I would get

> 'Pipe | a | song | about | a | Lamb

I would like to find a middle-ground between these two, as I need to keep the apostrophe in words such as *O'er* and the hyphens, but get rid of everything else.

I know that this topic has been seemingly exhausted on this forum, but I have spent the last four days trying every example offered and haven't been able to get them to work as advertised, so instead of tearing all of my hair out I thought I'd try posting a question.

Edit:

It seems that the reason a standard tokenizer wasn't working with my text was the result of some of the apostrophes being right/left leaning in odd places. I have produced my desired result using a bunch of `.replace()` instructions:

```
txt = txt.replace("\n", " ")
#formats the text so that the line break counts as a space
txt = txt.replace("”", " ")
#replaces stray quotation marks with a space
txt = txt.replace("“", " ")
#replaces stray quotation marks with a space
txt = txt.replace(" ’", " ")
#replaces a right leaning apostrophe with a space if it follows a space(which now includes line breaks)
txt = txt.replace(" ‘", " ")
#replaces a left leaning apostrophe with a space if it follows a space
```

I don't doubt that there is a way to consolidate all of those into one line of code, but I'm just really happy that it all works!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than replacing the punctuation, you could `split` on spaces then `strip` punctuation at the start and end of each word:

```
>>> import string
>>> phrase = "'This has punctuation, and it's hard to remove!'"
>>> [word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in phrase.split(" ")]
['This', 'has', 'punctuation', 'and', "it's", 'hard', 'to', 'remove']
```

This keeps apostrophes and hyphens within words, while removing punctuation at the start or end of words.

---

Note that standalone punctuation will be replaced by an empty string `""`:

```
>>> phrase = "This is - no doubt - punctuated"
>>> [word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in phrase.split(" ")]
['This', 'is', '', 'no', 'doubt', '', 'punctuated']
```

This is easy to filter out, as the empty string evaluates `False`:

```
filtered = [f for f in txt if f and f.lower() not in stopwords]
                            # ^ excludes empty string
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more than "struggling to get it to work"? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide example inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: Sorry, I was failing at getting the comment to format and submitted before it was ready. Just working out how to format it now.

Comment: Right, what I have is   `import string` `raw = open('file.txt', 'r').read()`  `output = open('Output/result.csv','w')`  `txt = raw.lower()`  `[word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in txt.split(" ")]`  And the result now just gives me a few random letters and the frequency they appear in the text. eg: e - 1635, t - 766, etc.

Comment: And to embarrass myself further, I can't get the comment to format properly. My sincerest apologies.

Comment: @wim unlike `its` and `it's` there's not much to confuse with `twas`! Although `astronauts'` and `astronauts` might be a problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for pointing that out, unfortunately it's still not working, with the CSV table now (in addition to including all of the punctuation) also offsetting the first column by one...

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have edited the comment again, hopefully it's slightly clearer where things are going wrong.

Comment: @E.Kori I don't think that's an offset, I think there are 284 empty strings `""` in your output (obviously, you can check by counting the actual `'little'`s). I have edited with a way to remove these. Not sure why `"thee?"` still has punctuation, you may need to find this string in your raw data and find out what surrounds it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have updated the code with your edit, and it removed the empty string count from the start of the table (thanks!). However, all of the punctuation is still attached to the words that precede/follow it, so the script doesn't seem to remove any of it? I thought that the  `.strip()`  would do that, but for some reason hasn't.

Comment: I can only suggest that you pick one of the words that still has punctuation and follow it through your code; `print txt`, `print filtered`. Do the same words appear with and without punctuation? What does [`string.punctuation`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation) contain (varies by C locale)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for all of your help, I eventually figured out the problem by combing through the original text file and edited my question.